# jQuery toggle class flickers

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to change the class of a logo, so it displays a different image. The first time the mouseenter event fires, though, it flickers -- this doesn't happen on mouseleave or subsequent mouseenter events. Any thoughts on why?

My HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5000/" class="logo" id="logo"></a>
```

My CSS:

```
.logo {
    background:url('logo.png');
    width:250px;
    height:42px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.logo-hover {
    background:url('logo-hover.png');
    width:250px;
    height:42px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

My rough jQuery:

```
$('#logo').mouseenter(function(){$(this).toggleClass('logo-hover')});
$('#logo').mouseleave(function(){$(this).toggleClass('logo-hover')});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the 'hover' image won't be requested from the server until you first use the class you've assigned to it. So on the first hover it has to download the image before showing it.

To fix this, use [sprite images](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) or alternatively [data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Comment: the only trouble data URIs is the lack of IE7 support, but I've used sprints before. That should do it.

Comment: IE7 is a pain, id agree. PS Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it answered your question ;0)

Answer (score 0):

It probably varies by browser, network connection speed, etc. That would explain why it only happens once - upon later events the image is already loaded.

My suggestion would be to put your images in a single sprite so it loads just once and then you can eliminate any network delays in changing out your image.

Another completely unrelated suggestion - find a way to consolidate your CSS. I see a lot of common properties between your .logo classes - float, display, width, etc. You can probably use a single class with perhaps :hover pseudo-classes to get the effect you want and keep your CSS simpler.

Comment: agree completely...I'd suggest adding example of how to do this. something like what jquery-ui does: .ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_666666_256x240.png); .ui-icon-triangle-1-n { background-position: 0 -16px; }

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply use :hover? Anyway, the solution is to use one image for both logos and change the background-position rather than the background-image.

Edit: You should put some content in your `a` element as well (same text as in the logo probably). You can use text-indent: -1000000px; to remove it with CSS.